# Slick - slides jump with centerMode and variable width

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider with centerMode true and variableWidth: true.

The center slide needs to be 2x bigger than the other slides.
All slides have a width of 80px but the center need to have 160px.

here's a fiddle and code of my problem (jsfiddle messed it up but you can see the "jump"):

```
$('#timeline').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '60px',
      slidesToShow: 5,
      variableWidth: true,
      arrows:false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xf365usn/15/

I'll post more code if needed. Any solutions to that?

Comment: I see all the slides as circles with the same size. The problem is the size or the jump from the overlapping?

Comment: the circles have all 80 bersides the center one, this one should have 160...jsfiddle messed it up

Comment: And the jump is the jump the slides made when overlapping?

Comment: no... when you have different widths.... see the fiddle.. it jumps there...

Comment: I think i need to change that fiddle. All the slides are the same size and overlapped. Ill try my best to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue with a fixed width on all slide with

```
.slick-slide { width:200px; }
```

and variableWidth: true
I also left centerMode on true and edited the slick-active slide to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the .slick-track some CSS animation transition it works well.`.slick-track { transition: all 0.3s ease; }`